# Cassandra for messaging

Tags: cassandra, messaging

I am now doing a small research to find a way to store huge volume of data (temporarily, till some consumers consume these messages) from various 'message producers' (source). The data come from different sources, say HTTP, FTP, SMPP or file upload, each type may have tens or hundreds of instances creating messages. The messages produced by them can grow so huge that the message consumers may lag behind in consuming the messages as the processes may take long or not short time. Now, the system uses RabbitMQ in some parts, but its performance drops when huge volume of unconsumed message grows (I'm also looking into improving its performance, but that's different). As an alternate, I am looking on to Apache Kafka which uses the disk for persisting messages.

As I read through many articles in the internet, I read some articles that talks about the Apache Cassandra with very fast write, processing a million inserts per second and similar volume reads. I was astonished, and tried to find some leads in using Cassandra for my case but with no clear results.

Assuming I have large number of message producers, can Cassandra (cluster) handle inserts (in batches) so faster (overall high throughput) that the producers does not throttle?

I am sure some among you could have used Cassandra for this or similar kind of use cases, share you experiences. (I am ready to provide you any more information if this does not suffice)

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Cassandra can handle writes very effectively. But in my experience, using it as a messaging system (queue and the likes) brings some technical constraints because of the [tombstones](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets).

Cassandra doesn't remove deleted rows immediately and marks them with a tomstone to be garbarge collected later. Overtime, if there are a lot of deletions (eg. dequeue messages), the overall performance will be hurt, and quite quickly.

You can go for Cassandra but you will have to implement work around for the tomstone problem (time bucket, multiple status tables).

IMHO, Apache Kafka is much more appropriate to the messaging use case and can also be scaled massively.

Comment: Nice answer. I think setting gc_grace_seconds value to a fairly appropriate value (keeping performance and gc overhead and additional storage caused by tombstones) can help you because Cassandra is designed for heavy/fast inserts with less read and deletes and thus may not be a better choice for you. Kafka is the one designed for such use cases.